# Neo4J count relationships of nodes separately

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my social media app I have a neo4j db for the FRIEND, POSTED, LIKE, COMMENT, SHARE Relations like this

Nodes

```
(User{user_id})
(Post{title, text, created, picture})
```

Edges

```
(User)-[:FRIEND]->(User)
(User)-[:POSTED]->(Post) 
(Post)-[:PINNED]->(User)
(User)-[:LIKE]->(Post)
(User)-[:SHARE]->(Post)
```

I'm looking for a query that returns all data from all Posts 
POSTED by me OR 
PINNED to me OR
POSTED AND PINNED to a FRIEND of me 
including the count of LIKE Relations and SHARE Relations of every single Post. Additionally to this, i want to return the user_id from every User with a POSTED Relation to one of these posts. 
All of this ORDER BY created DESC.

The result im looking for would be something like that

```
{ 
    {
        user_id:56,
        text:'This is a test',
        title:'This is a title',
        created:'2016.12.01.18.00.00'
        post_picture:'',
        likecount:9,
        sharecount:3
    },
    {
        user_id:52,
        text:'This is a test',
        title:'This is a title',
        created:'2016.12.01.17.00.00'
        post_picture:'',
        likecount:12,
        sharecount:4
    }
}
```

This doesn't work

```
MATCH (post)-[:POSTED]-(user:User)-[:FRIEND]-(friend:User)
WHERE (user{user_id:'97'})-[:POSTED]-(post)
OR (user{user_id:'97'})-[:PINNED]-(post)
OR (friend{user_id:'97'})-[:FRIEND]-(user)-[:PINNED]-(post) 
AND(friend{user_id:'97'})-[:FRIEND]-(user)-[:POSTED]-(post)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post)-[liked:LIKE]-(b:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post)-[share:SHARE]-(d:User)
WITH post, user, count(liked) as likecount, 
count(share) as sharecount
RETURN DISTINCT
user.user_id as user_id,
post.title as title,
post.text as text,
post.picture as post_picture,
post.created as created,
likecount,
sharecount,
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Is there even a way to get this all in one single query?

Answer (score 2):

This query should work:

```
MATCH (me:User {user_id: 123})
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:POSTED]->(p1)
WITH me, COLLECT(p1) AS posts
OPTIONAL MATCH (p2)-[:PINNED]->(me)
WITH me, posts + COLLECT(p2) AS posts
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:FRIEND]-(friend)-[:POSTED]->(p3)-[:PINNED]->(friend)
WITH me, posts + COLLECT(p3) AS posts
UNWIND posts AS post
WITH DISTINCT post
OPTIONAL MATCH (poster)-[:POSTED]->(post)
RETURN post, COUNT(()-[:LIKE]->(post)) AS likes, COUNT(()-[:SHARE]->(post)) AS shares, COLLECT(DISTINCT poster.user_id) AS posters
ORDER BY post.created DESC;
```

It collects the posts that match each criterion in the `posts` collection, filters out duplicates, finds the users who posted the posts, and returns your results in the desired order.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This query perfectly makes sense to me, but whenever i try this in my code, i get an "unexpected failure" at the line where i call result.hasNext()

Comment: Since this is a purely Cypher-related question, you should create a new question and include the relevant details about your code.

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work? What are you getting back? This would be an invalid cypher query, because of a dangling comma before ORDERing.

Here's the cleaned up version of your cypher query.

```
MATCH (post)-[:POSTED]-(user:User)-[:FRIEND]-(friend:User)
WHERE (user{user_id:'97'})-[:POSTED]-(post)
OR (user{user_id:'97'})-[:PINNED]-(post)
OR (friend{user_id:'97'})-[:FRIEND]-(user)-[:PINNED]-(post) 
AND(friend{user_id:'97'})-[:FRIEND]-(user)-[:POSTED]-(post)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post)-[liked:LIKE]-(b:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (post)-[share:SHARE]-(d:User)
WITH post, user, count(liked) as likecount, 
count(share) as sharecount
RETURN DISTINCT
user.user_id as user_id,
post.title as title,
post.text as text,
post.picture as post_picture,
post.created as created,
likecount,
sharecount,
ORDER BY created DESC
```

If that doesn't work, can you provide test db or a cypher statement that creates the graph that you want to operate on? This will be helpful when coming up with a good solution for your problem.